# pause button is not working for video in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, video

when i click on video screen which should play/pause, which is working fine. But html5 video default controls(play/pause buttons) are not working.

for this I have added event listener, now play button is working fine but pause button is not working.

**here I am unable to pause the video through pause button.**

please help me on this. thanks in advance.......

```
    <video id="myVideo" onclick="playPause(this)" width="320" height="240" poster="images/Koala.jpg" controls="controls">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="videos/clipcanvas.mp4" />
    </video>
```

script code:

```
function playPause(myVideo) {

        myVideo.addEventListener('play', function() {
            myVideo.play();
        }, false);

        if (myVideo.paused) {
            myVideo.play();

        } else {
            myVideo.pause();
        }
    }
```